# What is the general name/description for what I thought was "Makeout Creek"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, american-english, slang, phrase-requests

In The Simpsons, and many old movies from/set in the 1950s, there is a common scene where a couple sits in a parked car at what appears to be a high hill, in the evening or night, looking out over the city underneath. They're kissing/making out. It's romantic and stuff.

For some reason, I have internally labeled this the "Makeout Creek". But a "creek" doesn't seem to match: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Creek

I don't really understand what a "creek" is, even after reading that page.

What is the general description/name for the place located high up in the mountains (or a hill?) where young couples drive to make out/kiss and (barely) look out over the city?

Would be nice to finally get this straightened out.

Comment: In not-quite-mediaeval times, a place for such secret meetings was known as a _trysting place_.

Comment: I suppose if the car’s springs are rusty it might be “Makeout creak”…

Comment: [Make-Out Point](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MakeOutPoint) seems to be a TV/Movie trope

Comment: That wiktionary page is for *Creek*, the proper noun, rather than *creek*.  The proper noun *Creek* is the name of a Native American tribe.  A generic *creek* is a small river or stream.  If there were a popular term "makeout creek," it would probably be referring a stream, rather than a member of the Creek tribe.  But there's no such expression anyway.

Comment: Many cultures have places where young lovers are semi-officially allowed some degree privacy for getting to know each other.  In one region of China, by tradition, a special purpose covered bridge was built with a series of benches that were hidden from each other by the beams holding up the roof of the bridge. This was known as a lover's bridge. The symbolism of a bridge for lovers is fairly clear and fairly romantic.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that this television and movie trope is referred to as "makeout point".

> A standard teenage hang out where all sorts of canoodling takes place in cars...Often involves a tourist-trap-type scenic bluff, so as to overlook the city lights at night

[TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MakeOutPoint)

I don't know where the editors of *TV Tropes* get the names for their entries, and I was skeptical that this term was in widespread use, but you can find quite a number of citations in Google Books.<sup>1</sup>

The reason I was skeptical is that I've never heard anyone use this term.  That's likely because these "makeout points" are common in movies and TV, but not in the real world.  Most cities don't have a perfect secluded viewpoint that you can drive right up to.

Of course, people, especially people without their own houses, do need to find places to make out.  If there's a place where people commonly go to make out, it might be called a *makeout spot*.<sup>2</sup>

It also looks like *makeout spot* is at least occasionally used to refer to the TV and movie trope: "Since you didn't have a famed 'makeout spot' on a leafy hill overlooking the town (thanks, every teen movie ever)" ([*Cosmo*](https://www.cosmopolitan.com/sex-love/news/a63849/high-school-places-everyone-remembers-making-out/))

---

1. Some examples of "makeout point":

> Lori thought they were headed up to Johnson's Reservoir to the makeout point.

[The Coy Circle](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Coy_Circle/Z_C_DAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22makeout+point%22&pg=PT148&printsec=frontcover)

> They were parked at Makeout Point, a discreet distance away from the other cars

[Out of the Madhouse](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Out_of_the_Madhouse/Gow2DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22makeout+point%22&pg=PT96&printsec=frontcover)

> Many of the makeout point scenes were filmed on Mulholland Drive near the current home of the Skirball Cultural Center.

[Grease is the Word: Exploring a Cultural Phenomenon](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Grease_Is_the_Word/8Lm9DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22makeout+point%22&pg=PA53&printsec=frontcover)

2. For some reason, the top Google results for "makeout spot" are mostly reviews or recommendations for these kinds of places, e.g. ["Best make out spot in Los Angeles, CA - Yelp"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwir14Ko8dvyAhWTFjQIHdMQD9MQFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yelp.com%2Fsearch%3Ffind_desc%3Dmakeout%2Bspot%26find_loc%3DLos%2BAngeles%252C%2BCA&usg=AOvVaw2mKW7zqhJe6yqXNPakabGt), ["Where's The Best Makeout Spot In The Treasure Valley?"](https://mix106radio.com/wheres-the-best-makeout-spot-in-the-treasure-valley/), ["Best makeout spot | Newcity"](https://www.newcity.com/2015/11/05/best-makeout-spot/)

Comment: “make-out spot” is probably the most common these days… although I wonder what effect the pandemic has had on “parking” (which is what we called going to a make-out spot when I was in high school).

Comment: The lock-down has strengthened the idiom of "Netflix and chill." Nobody is watching any Netflix, and there won't be much chill. But that's what it's called.

Answer (score 4):

I would call it [lovers’ lane](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lovers%27+lane)

> The generic name for a place, often one with a scenic view, that teenagers and young adults go to kiss and potentially engage in other sexual activity, typically in a car.
> *If a boy takes you to lovers' lane, it's not because he wants to talk about the weather, OK?*

The “[lane](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lane)” is probably used in the sense of “a narrow country road” or “A narrow way or passage between walls, hedges, or fences“, not “a strip delineated on a street or highway”. This term might be old fashioned, but I think it’s still well known.

Comment: Ah. Yes. "Lover's lane" sounds familiar, although "lane" still sounds odd to me, as if it's a "lane" in a motor road.

Comment: @S.B. -  Do you know the muffin man?

Comment: @S.B. The point about "lane" meaning a narrow thoroughfare, often but not universally in a rural setting, is the original one. The use of the same word to describe a part of a wide modern highway is no more than a hundred years old. The idea of a lane in a running track is a bit older but a "country lane" and a "lovers' lane" are hundreds of years old. I'm afraid that you'll have to put up with it.